# Inserting using CSV

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with two fields Name and ID.
Name comes from input parameter @Name and ID comes a CSV @CSVID.
I have a spilt function that return a temp table .

My stored proc is

```
INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable
(
    Name, 
    ID
 )
 VALUES
(

    (SELECT @Name, id FROM dbo.Split(@CSVID))
)
```

My split function

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Split] (@InStr VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS @TempTab TABLE
   (id int not null)
AS
BEGIN
    ;-- Ensure input ends with comma
SET @InStr = REPLACE(@InStr + ',', ',,', ',')
DECLARE @SP INT
DECLARE @VALUE VARCHAR(1000)
WHILE PATINDEX('%,%', @INSTR ) <> 0 
BEGIN
   SELECT  @SP = PATINDEX('%,%',@INSTR)
   SELECT  @VALUE = LEFT(@INSTR , @SP - 1)
   SELECT  @INSTR = STUFF(@INSTR, 1, @SP, '')
   INSERT INTO @TempTab(id) VALUES (@VALUE)
END
RETURN
END
```

So what I want is

say 
    @Name = 'John Doe' 
    @CSVID = '1,2'

Then I want the result of insert to be

```
 Name    ID
 John     1
 Jhon     2
```

I saw so many example but they were all so complicated. I just a simple explanation as to how insert works if the subquery

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Split(@CSVID)
```

returns more than 1 value.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable(Name, ID)
SELECT  @Name,
        id
FROM dbo.Split(@CSVID)
```

Comment: So i return id from my split function. And added SELECT id FROM dbo.Split(@CSVID) in insert. it does not work. Can you point where did i go wrong

Comment: @Neha But does `SELECT id FROM dbo.Split(@CSVID)` return something?, or it throws an error?. What is the actual column name of your function table?

Comment: Yes if i pass SELECT id FROM dbo.Split('1,2'). I get values 1 and 2. No error there. but when I insert i get error  "Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression."

Comment: @Neha I updated my answer so it uses `id` instead of the `InsertYourColumnNameHere`, but are you using the code I posted?, because it is different to the one you have on your question. I ask you that because I'm not using a subquery, so not sure where are you getting that error from

Comment: Sorry to be a pain but I am not understanding completely. In the script you posted @Name becomes a part of Select. Now the Split function added in the mail question returns only id. How will that work.

Comment: @Neha Sorry, but did you try it?. The `SELECT` can take a parameter, in this case, `@name`. Since it's a scalar value, it will repeat that value for every row returned from your function. That's all there is

Comment: Yes i did try it. I don't know where this makes a difference or not but I have two inserts. 1st insert returns @Name. Now that name is then inserted along with CSVID in second table.  When i try what you asked I get error There are more columns in the INSERT statement than values specified in the VALUES clause. The number of values in the VALUES clause must match the number of columns specified in the INSERT statement. Updated my query in main question for insert

Comment: @Neha Well, I can't help you if you are using code that I don't see. Take a look to my answer, there are 2 columns defined on the `INSERT` and 2 columns on the `SELECT`, so that error shouldn't happen there.